# NoClassDefFound for JTDS JDBC while trying to connect to SQL Server

Tags: java, android, jdbc, android-asynctask

I'm working on a login that gets a list of usernames and passwords from an SQL server. Using another program I am sure that the URL for the SQL server is working and that the server works. So it starts in the main activity shown here:

activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp.Login">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="171dp"
            android:text="@string/username"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/username_textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/password_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/password_input"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/username_textView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/username_textView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
            android:text="@string/password"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/username_input"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
            android:onClick="CheckLogin"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Login.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
  }

  public void CheckLogin(View v){
      /* Check SQL server to see if login is correct*/

      Log.d("TEst", "------------------------Begin");
      EditText usernameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_input);
      EditText passwordEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_input);

      Log.d("TEst", "--------------------------Part1");

      String username = usernameEdit.getText().toString();
      String password = passwordEdit.getText().toString();

      Log.d("TEst","---------------------------Part2");

      //Get Login cred table
      WebTalker server = new WebTalker();
      GlobalVars global = new GlobalVars();

      Log.d("TEst","---------------------------Part3");

      ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> logins = server.GetTable("dbo.Logins", this);//TODO: insert table name here for logins

      Log.d("TEst","---------------------------Part4");

      for (int i = 0; i <= logins.size(); i++) {
          if (logins.get(i).get(0) == username) {
              if (logins.get(i).get(1) == password) {
                  global.setString("username", username, this.getApplicationContext());
                  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              }
          }
      }

      server.PopUp("Invalid username or password", this, R.layout.activity_login);
  }

}
```

Then after I enter anything into the username and password fields and hit the "Login" button, this script launches:

WebTalker.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Talks to SQL server and does requested action
 *
 * TableArray Format
 *
 * tableArray[row][column]
 */

public class WebTalker {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> table = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    private static final Object waitObj = new Object();
    private Activity activ;

    private String error;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tableArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    private ResultSet rs;
    private Statement stmt;
    private Connection con;

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> GetTable(String tableName, Activity act) {
        activ = act;
        new CheckServer().execute(tableName);

        //Wait for Async to finish
        synchronized (waitObj) {
            try {
                waitObj.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                PopUp("Error: Synchronization error", activ, R.layout.activity_login);
            }
        }
        return table;
    }

    private void postResult(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> asyncresult) {
        table = asyncresult;
        synchronized (waitObj) {
            waitObj.notify();
        }
    }

    private class CheckServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        /* Fetch info from server and run through it */

        //TODO:Change this later
        private String connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.173.139.55:1433/master/user=Admin;password=123;";

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... tableName) {
            //Make sure that tablename is a directory to the table

            try {

                //GetDriver
                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                    //Connect
                    Log.d("TEst", "-------------------------Start Connection");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

                    Log.d("TEst","---------------------------Connected");

                    //Create and execute SQL statement
                    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName[0];

                    stmt = con.createStatement();
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);


                    int column = 0;
                    int row = 0;

                    ArrayList<String> tempArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                    //Run through the data
                    while(rs.next()) {
                        //compile to array
                        while(rs.getString(column) != null) {
                            tempArray.add(rs.getString(column));
                            column += 1;
                        }
                        tableArray.add(tempArray);
                        row += 1;
                        column = 0;
                    }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.d("TEst","---------------------------" + e.toString());
                error = "Error: SQL Exception";
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("TEst","---------------------------" + e.toString());
                error = "Error: ClassNotFoundException";
            } finally {
                //Close Connections
                if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(SQLException e) {}
                if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(SQLException e) {}
                if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(SQLException e) {}
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            if (error != null) {
                PopUp(error, activ, R.layout.activity_login);
            }
            postResult(tableArray);
        }

    }

    public void PopUp(String errorMessage, final Activity act, final int layoutToLoad){
        /*Create a pop-up dialog box containing the errormessage*/

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);

        final TextView view = new TextView(act);
        view.setText(errorMessage);
        view.setTextSize(18);
        view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Return", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            act.setContentView(layoutToLoad);
            }
        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

The Error shown below pops up when the program hits this line:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

Error Message:

```
05-25 17:03:18.292 22223-23272/com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
  Process: com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp, PID: 22223
  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/ietf/jgss/GSSManager;
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.createGssToken(TdsCore.java:4400)
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.sendMSLoginPkt(TdsCore.java:1971)
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:617)
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371)
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:237)
      at com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp.WebTalker$CheckServer.doInBackground(WebTalker.java:84)
      at com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp.WebTalker$CheckServer.doInBackground(WebTalker.java:67)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762) 
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.createGssToken(TdsCore.java:4400) 
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.sendMSLoginPkt(TdsCore.java:1971) 
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:617) 
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371) 
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184) 
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569) 
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:237) 
      at com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp.WebTalker$CheckServer.doInBackground(WebTalker.java:84) 
      at com.qrscanner.mahindra.estimateapp.WebTalker$CheckServer.doInBackground(WebTalker.java:67) 
      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304) 
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Thank You!

Comment: Looks like the jar file that has the class "org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager" is not in the apk, will have to add it to the lib directory.

Comment: I've been looking around and can't find the file, but I did find this [link](https://github.com/ubergeek42/weechat-android/issues/237). It shows someone with a similar issue that sets "PreferredAuthentications" as "password", but I'm not sure how to translate that to my issue. @tik27 (And thank you for the quick response!)

Comment: Why would Android Studio need to connect to an SQL Server? Do you mean your Android App?

Comment: Android apps should not directly use JDBC, as it's a security flaw (you're storing credentials and database url directly in your app) and causes resource leaks easily... Besides that, your code is susceptible to SQL injection

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the info, as this is more of a learning project, and my first time working with databases. Would you be able to point me towards an article or question to better understand how I should be using JDBC? Just to humor my curiosity, I'm still curious about what caused the error.